# Processor that would process an Object (say a message you received)

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry for being a little abstract but I have attempted to concoct something simple but it seems to spiral out of control. So I was thinking maybe I am taking the wrong approach.

Here's what I am trying to do:

> When I get a message it gets de-serialized into its own class. I would like to use a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to choose a message processor that would be able to process the message

***How would you do it?***

Here are my attempts at this that got very convoluted the closer I got to the goal. I mean, it works but I would have thought it would be cleaner than this so just thinking I must be going about this wrong:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801156/cant-seem-to-get-generic-covariance-contravariance-to-work
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784981/why-is-thisinterfacet-not-of-type-interfacet-using-an-is-keyword-comparison
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777762/cant-convert-from-abstractgeneric-to-concreteabstractconcretegeneric

Here's my code (**but I am looking for ideas to avoid the MessageProcessorWrapper**). How would you re-write it?:

```
public interface IBaseMessage { 
   public int ID() { get; set; }
}

public interface IMessageProcessor<in T> where T : IBaseMessage {
            void Process(T msg);
        }

public class RRMessage : IBaseMessage {
          public string Text {get; set;}
          public DateTime RRProcessDate {get; set; }
        }

public class BaseMessageProcessor {
         public int MessageProcID{ get; set; }
         public BaseMessageProcessor(int mid) {
            MessageProcID = mid;
         }
      }

public class RRMessageProcessor : BaseMessageProcessor, IMessageProcessor<RRMessage> {
            public void Process(RRMessage msg) {
                WriteToDatabase(msg);
                UpdateInternalTrackers(msg);
                Console.WriteLine("Processed RRMessage");
            }
        }

public class ProcessorWrapper<T> : IMessageProcessor<IBaseMessage> {
    private readonly IMessageProcessor<T> inner;
    public ProcessorWrapper(IMessageProcessor<T> inner) { this.inner = inner; }

    public void Process(IBaseMessage msg)
    {
        if(msg is T) { inner.Process((T)msg); }
        else throw new ArgumentException("Invalid message type");
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MyTestFixture {
    public Dictionary<Type, IMessageProcessor<IBaseMessage>> MessageProcessors = new Dictionary<Type, IMessageProcessor<IBaseMessage>>();


    [Test]
    public void Test1() {
         var msgProcessor = new RRMessageProcessor();
         MessageProcessors.Add(typeof(RRMessage), new ProcessorWrapper<RRMessage>(msgProcessor);
         }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you  and welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you're looking for, but this bit of code casts `msg` twice: `if(msg is T) { inner.Process((T)msg); }`. You can cast it once by using `as`, e.g. `var m = msg as T; if (m != null) inner.Process(m);` Also if you're actually writing the if bit on one line (as I love to do for one-liners) then I don't see the point of using curly braces on that line, though I guess that's just a style issue. You didn't use it for the `else` part after all.

And I'm sure in "real life" you won't have a test called "Test1", so I won't say anything about that...